# Is it possible to get persistent RAM disk with Imdisk?

Tags: performance, ramdisk

I have moved my JDK, workspace and Tomcat server to a RAM disk which is created with the help of Imdisk tool.

This move has beefed up my Eclipse IDE and my productivity.

But I loose my virtual disk whenever I boot up my machine. Is it a way to persist RAM drive and it's content?

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit with 8GB of actual RAM.

Comment: I use an SSD which has much the same effect with more capacity. ;)

Comment: +1 for @Peter: SSDs are not *that* expensive any more and *well* worth their money (even more so if you can get the company to pay for them!).

Comment: Also it seems to be better-suited for [SU], since you don't seem to be looking for a programming solution.

Comment: dunno, my ssds are still much slower than a ram disk. IMO ssds are great for those situations that don't require a ram disk, just like HDDs are great for those situations that don't require an SSD - however a lot of people on the internet (not you guys but other places) love to write that ram disks are absolutely useless just because they are not useful for their own needs.

Answer (score 4):

Commands to automate this are in the `FAQ` for `Imdisk` :

http://reboot.pro/topic/15593-faqs-and-how-tos/

There are ways to have scripts run at windows startup (to load the disk image) and at windows shutdown (to save the ramdisk to the disk image).

Chris

Answer (score 4):

The IMDisk Toolkit wraps IMDisk and has a startup option: http://reboot.pro/files/download/284-imdisk-toolkit/

Comment: This link seems to be dead already. Other answer link to valid FAQ

Comment: ImDisk Toolkit rocks! Tiny, easy, and offers persistence. Available here in 2019: https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/